# DukeScript: How do native calls into JavaScript work?

Tags: knockout.js, dukescript

I'm struggling to understand how "native method" calls in DukeScript work.
In particular, the ones where no body is specified in the @JavascriptBody annotation. [For example](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/porting_knockout_components_to_dukescript):

```
@JavaScriptResource(value = "userEntryComponent.js")
public final class UserEntryWidget {

    private UserEntryWidget() {
    }

    @JavaScriptBody(args = {}, body = "")
    public static native void registerComponent();
}
```

Where is the "registerComponent()" method defined?
In knockout there's a javascript function called "ko.components.register".
So "registerComponent" must be a sort of wrapper around "ko.components.register".

Another example of a native method call without body is [here](https://github.com/eppleton/FXGameEngine/blob/master/dukescript-support/src/main/java/de/eppleton/fx2d/dukescript/JQuery.java):

```
@JavaScriptResource("jquery-1.11.0.min.js")
public class JQuery {

    @JavaScriptBody(args = {},body="")
    public static native void init();   
}
```

So, in this case, what's "init()"? is it a Java method or a JavaScript function?

Comment: I haven't picked a good example here, as the @JavaScriptResource case is very particular in which the method name in it doesn't really matter, it just triggers a load for that resource (See Jiri's answer below).

Comment: The generic case of providing an implementation for JavaScript native method is described here: http://bits.netbeans.org/html+java/dev/net/java/html/js/package-summary.html#post-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully understand why the code looks magical. However if you try to comment out the **init** method, you should see error during *javac* complication:

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
JQuery.java:[10,8] At least one method needs @JavaScriptBody
annotation. Otherwise it is not guaranteed the resource will
ever be loaded
```

The error line is the line with **@JavaScriptResource** usage. The **init** method definition is really empty and does nothing. But once called, it enforces load of resource defined in **@JavaScriptResource**.

In the knockout case, the *ko.components.register* is defined by the *knockout.js* resource file. The method name *registerComponent* can be arbitrary, it is there to just trigger the load of the *knockout.js* resource.

Comment: Anyway, this case is quite specific, and it doesn't cover the generic case in which a body is specified. The mystery is how native calls are evaluated by DukeScript at runtime. I keep getting UnsatisfiedLinkErrors (in Eclipse) and that hasn't to do with generated code as there is no generated code for native javascript calls. Is asm-5.0.jar being used?

Comment: I see that's the complicated bit that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't: http://bits.netbeans.org/html+java/dev/net/java/html/js/package-summary.html#post-process

Comment: I've just added asm.jar as a dependency and that helped. Not sure why the classes are not processed at compile time. Does the class scanning and class postprocessing happen during different Maven phases? perhaps I need to specify that in the pom. This problem occurs for me only when running the plugin using the maven-processor-pugin, which is Eclipse friendly.