# DukeScript: how to access the Java model from the JavaScript context?

Tags: knockout.js, dukescript

This is related to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608556/how-to-debug-javascript-in-dukescript) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631969/dukescript-how-do-native-calls-into-javascript-work).

I've read the excellent documentation ["Using the Knockout API"](https://dukescript.com/knockout4j.html).
That explains how the context is set of a specific widget with knockout bindings.

Now I'd like to be able to access Java models from the Firebug command line, as I would normally do when I access the ViewModel in Javascript using KnockoutJS in a browser.
Firebug doesn't know about "$root", basically I don't know how, and whether it'd be possible at all, to access the Java model at all and call @Function methods.
That would make for a cool REPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [ko.dataFor and ko.contextFor](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) and it might be easier to just use
`Model = ko.dataFor(document.body);`

Comment: thanks Jaroslav, I didn't know the ko.dataFor method, and yeah, I've binding it to document.body is also a good idea, no need for extra divs

Comment: one thing: "ko" doesn't exist before calling Models.toRaw(), true? Models.toRaw() is another mysterious entitiy

Answer (score 0):

Sucess!!!

Here's the trick, I've created a custom binding. In the custom binding init() method, the viewModel is passed. Then I just save the Model into a JavaScript variable.

Step 1: Custom Binding definition

```
  @net.java.html.js.JavaScriptBody(
      args = {},  body = 
        "ko.bindingHandlers.Model = {" +
            "init: function( element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel ){" +
            "Model = viewModel;" +
            "}" +
        "};"
  )
  public static native void registerModel();
```

Step 2: declare a div in the page with this data-bind:

```
<div data-bind="Model"></div>
```

Step 3: register the custom binding in main,onPageLoad():

```
    MyResource.registerModel();
    MyResource.loadFirebug();
    d.applyBindings();
```

Step 4: access your model observables and methods from the Firebug console (Model....)

Perhaps there's a more elegant way to data-bind the Firebug div directly, but I haven't managed, perhaps because since Firebug is loaded asynchronously, after applyBindings() is called.

[image]